# scroll does not work when max-height is 100%

Tags: css

I'm facing an issue where when my max-height is set to 500px, the scroll appears. However, if i set the height to 100%, the scroll will never appear for one of my tables. Strange enough, my other table works fine.

**scss code:**

```
.card-box {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 24px 0 rgb(34 41 47 / 10%);
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  padding: 10px;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;

  .ant-tabs-tab {
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .ant-table-tbody {
    color: #222;
  }

  .h6-title {
    color: blue !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    font-size: 32px !important;
    margin-left: 5px !important;
  }
}
```

**If i set to 500px:**
[image]

**If i set to 100%:**
[image]

Comment: Use `min-height` instead.

Comment: 100% height seems to be greater than 500px, and that seems to be enough to accommodate the rendered table. So what's the issue? You can also set the scroll to auto instead.

Comment: its enough here cause i zoomed out, however if at 100% zoom, part of the table will be hidden and I won't be able to see it